Trying to find out which trim package my 2006 Kia Optima is equipped with!
2006 Kia Optima with 2.7(?) liter engine. I cannot find the information I need, anywhere.
Even using the VIN I don't find the information I need!
I get limited information on NTSA website.
Where else can I find accurate data on my vehicle?
Unfortunately, Kia doesn't have any info online and I live in a very rural area, far from any dealerships!
Thanks for any assistance!

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

The easiest way is to call a Kia dealership. They can look the information up for you and let you know.
Looking online, it shows there were only two trim levels for the 2006 Kia Optima, the LX and EX. The EX will be the "up" model. Most likely since your car has the 2.7L V6, it is the EX model. The 2.4L I4 would come in the LX model.

Thank you so very much for your help!
